# Nginx, try_files not working

Tags: nginx

Have this situation

```
set $static_root /home/....
set $folder ...

location @vincent {
  proxy_pass http://vincent;
}

location ~* "/img/([a-z0-9\-]{2,5})/([a-z]{1,3})/([0-9]{1,2}\.jpg)" {

  set $cache $static_root/cached/$folder/$1/$2/$3;
  set $cache_common $static_root/cached/common/$1/$2/$3;


  try_files $cache $cache_common @vincent;

  #if (-f $cache) {
  #    return 301; break;
  #
}
```

With this config, I have a @vincent fallback, but commented "if" WORKS, i.e. I have 301 page if I uncomment if-block. This means cached file exists, but try_files wont serve it, why?

Comment: What is your complete nginx configuration? Most likely reason here is invalid `root` directive, and wrong relative path specification for `try_files`. Show me the complete configuration and full paths to the desired directories, then a proper answer can be given.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9326180
just replaced domain and project names

Comment: Got it, to make try_files work you need to specify root directive inside location, and make $cache relative

    location ~* "/img/([a-z0-9\-]{2,5})/([a-z]{1,3})/([0-9]{1,2}\.jpg)" {
      root /home/ex0rcist/ruby/project/current/static;
      set $cache /cached/$folder/$1/$2/$3;
    }

Comment: Specifying `root` under location isn't a good practice. See http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls first paragraph.